# keeping the clean code in java while performing git operation

Tags: git, code-cleanup

How to validate the code(like removing unused headers/code, duplicate lines/methods etc) during git operation like commit/push?

Comment: Look into using Git hooks.  You could actually create both client side and server side hooks.  But note that a few of your asks (e.g. remove unused headers) often falls to the responsibility of the IDE to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the code, that means you should not do it on the server side (with post-receive hook)

You might have a [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) (still on the server side) which would *reject* improper commits.

But you can set a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks) on the client side, or you setup a [clean script, that is a content filter driver](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_a), which would do the same on checkin.